# Kotlin: RangeSeekBar library setSelectedMinValue function not found?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin with the RangeSeekBar library in my Android App. I'm trying to set a ranged seek-bar in the onCreate method of an Activity class. I have a ranged seek-bar called "seekbar_age_settings".

This single line of code is giving the error "Expression 'selectedMinValue' of type 'Number!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"

```
seekbar_age_settings.selectedMinValue(18)
```

In Kotlin selectedMinValue serves as both the set and get functions. In this case I'm trying to use the set function.

In the example of the RangeSeekBar github, written in Java, this is used:

```
rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(20);
rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(88);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply to set the value using the "=" rather than invoking. As is the way in Kotlin.

```
seekbar_age_settings.selectedMinValue = 18
```